# Xarray concatenate netcdf files without memory issue

Tags: python, memory, merge, netcdf, python-xarray

**Goal:** concatenate 3 netcdf files with **xarray**.

**Problem:** merging them blows up the memory. Altogether the files are 3.75GB, and my pc has 32GB of RAM.

**Context:** set of 3 netcdf files (weighing together 3.75 GB) that each cover a part of an area of interest. They all have the same height (`y`), but different width (`x`). The 3rd axis (`t`, for time) can overlap but not necessarily (files **0** and **1** can have values for `t0`, but file **2** might not). *See below for a sketch illustrating the problem*

**Question:** Why does my memory blow up while the files are so small compared to the total RAM ? When running python without anything opened, 10% of the RAM is already taken. That leaves approximately 28GB of free RAM.

**Code that I tried:**

```
import netCDF4
import numpy
import xarray as xr


ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('vx*.nc',combine = 'nested', concat_dim="time")
ds.to_netcdf('Total_vx.nc')
```

I also tried using **ncrcat** but I am on Windows, I couldn't figure it out. I tried installing **nctoolkit** without success because of the **cdo** issue.

**Dataset:**

```
################################################
print(ds_0)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (mid_date: 17759, x: 83, y: 517)
Coordinates:
  * mid_date        (mid_date) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-22T15:56:47.889802752 ....
  * x               (x) float64 -3.345e+06 -3.345e+06 ... -3.335e+06 -3.335e+06
  * y               (y) float64 3.62e+05 3.619e+05 ... 3.002e+05 3.001e+05
Data variables:
    vx              (mid_date, y, x) float32 ...
    date_dt         (mid_date) timedelta64[ns] 36 days 00:00:01.957392 ... 46...
    mission_img1    (mid_date) object 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' ... 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S'
    mission_img2    (mid_date) object 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' ... 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S'
    satellite_img1  (mid_date) object '1A' '2B' '1A' '1A' ... '2B' '2B' '2A'
    satellite_img2  (mid_date) object '1A' '2B' '1A' '1A' ... '2A' '2A' '2B'
Attributes: (12/18)
    GDAL_AREA_OR_POINT:         Area
    author:                     ITS_LIVE, a NASA MEaSUREs project (its-live.j...
    autoRIFT_parameter_file:    http://its-live-data.s3.amazonaws.com/autorif...
    datacube_software_version:  1.0
    date_created:               29-Mar-2022 18:26:48
    date_updated:               06-Jun-2022 20:45:39
                        ...
    s3:                         s3://its-live-data/datacubes/v02/N50W140/ITS_...
    skipped_granules:           s3://its-live-data/datacubes/v02/N50W140/ITS_...
    time_standard_img1:         UTC
    time_standard_img2:         UTC
    title:                      ITS_LIVE datacube of image_pair velocities
    url:                        https://its-live-data.s3.amazonaws.com/datacu...


########################################################
print(ds_1)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (mid_date: 17759, x: 83, y: 517)
Coordinates:
  * mid_date        (mid_date) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-22T15:56:47.889802752 ....
  * x               (x) float64 -3.325e+06 -3.325e+06 ... -3.315e+06 -3.315e+06
  * y               (y) float64 3.62e+05 3.619e+05 ... 3.002e+05 3.001e+05
Data variables:
    vx              (mid_date, y, x) float32 ...
    date_dt         (mid_date) timedelta64[ns] ...
    mission_img1    (mid_date) object ...
    mission_img2    (mid_date) object ...
    satellite_img1  (mid_date) object ...
    satellite_img2  (mid_date) object ...
Attributes: (12/18)
    GDAL_AREA_OR_POINT:         Area
    author:                     ITS_LIVE, a NASA MEaSUREs project (its-live.j...
    autoRIFT_parameter_file:    http://its-live-data.s3.amazonaws.com/autorif...
    datacube_software_version:  1.0
    date_created:               29-Mar-2022 18:26:48
    date_updated:               06-Jun-2022 20:45:39
                        ...
    s3:                         s3://its-live-data/datacubes/v02/N50W140/ITS_...
    skipped_granules:           s3://its-live-data/datacubes/v02/N50W140/ITS_...
    time_standard_img1:         UTC
    time_standard_img2:         UTC
    title:                      ITS_LIVE datacube of image_pair velocities
    url:                        https://its-live-data.s3.amazonaws.com/datacu...

######################################################################
print(ds_2)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (mid_date: 17759, x: 42, y: 517)
Coordinates:
  * mid_date        (mid_date) datetime64[ns] 2017-06-22T15:56:47.889802752 ....
  * x               (x) float64 -3.305e+06 -3.305e+06 ... -3.3e+06 -3.3e+06
  * y               (y) float64 3.62e+05 3.619e+05 ... 3.002e+05 3.001e+05
Data variables:
    vx              (mid_date, y, x) float32 ...
    date_dt         (mid_date) timedelta64[ns] ...
    mission_img1    (mid_date) object ...
    mission_img2    (mid_date) object ...
    satellite_img1  (mid_date) object ...
    satellite_img2  (mid_date) object ...
Attributes: (12/18)
    GDAL_AREA_OR_POINT:         Area
    author:                     ITS_LIVE, a NASA MEaSUREs project (its-live.j...
    autoRIFT_parameter_file:    http://its-live-data.s3.amazonaws.com/autorif...
    datacube_software_version:  1.0
    date_created:               29-Mar-2022 18:26:48
    date_updated:               06-Jun-2022 20:45:39
                        ...
    s3:                         s3://its-live-data/datacubes/v02/N50W140/ITS_...
    skipped_granules:           s3://its-live-data/datacubes/v02/N50W140/ITS_...
    time_standard_img1:         UTC
    time_standard_img2:         UTC
    title:                      ITS_LIVE datacube of image_pair velocities
    url:                        https://its-live-data.s3.amazonaws.com/datacu...
```

Sketch of the problem:
[image]

Comment: These are likely zipped Netcdf files so will take up more space in memory than on disk. Do you have dask installed? Try to modify your work flow as it should help you get round the memory issues https://docs.xarray.dev/en/v0.9.2/dask.html

Comment: Can you print ds_0, ds_1, ds_2 and ds ?

Comment: Yeah - getting a more precise understanding of the dimensions would certainly be helpful here. But even from your drawing it looks like the dimensions are not all aligned except for one dimension. The xarray data model assumes there is a clause for every combination of all axes, so if your data have differing dimensions in x and time your result will expand to include the combinatorial product of these dims. Between that and file compression I think you could easily end up with something many times the size on disk.

Comment: To help we’ll need to know more about these files and also why/how you want them joined. For example, is time not important as a dimension?

Comment: Thank you all for your insights. @RobertWilson I edited my question by printing the variables. My netcdf files are not zipped (I added a screen capture of my folder to my question)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado you are right, they are not aligned on the x-axis. I managed to combine much smaller files organized the same way by converting everything to numpy arrays and concatenating them together. But it was tideous, not efficient and memory hungry (I couldn't do that for these new files). 

Time is an important dimension: when I concatenated the smaller files, I had to "extend" the time axis for each `ds` files, and fill it with NaNs.

Comment: @RobertWilson I used your link and got something, but I don't understand what I did:
`ds = xr.open_mfdataset('vx*.nc',combine = 'nested', concat_dim="time", chunks={'mid_date':10})`
Then:
`ds.to_netcdf('test.nc')`

Saves a 11.2GB file. I can open it: `ds = xr.open_dataset('test.nc', chunks:{'mid_date':1000})`.

To plot mean along the time axis: 
`v_mean = ds.vx.mean(dim='mid_date', skipna=True)
plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.imshow(v_mean[0])
plt.show()`

My question is: how can I "squeeze" the dataset (get rid of time:3) ? `ds: Dimensions: (mid_date: 17759, x: 208, y: 517, time: 3)`

Comment: @Nihilum As MichaelDelgao points out you are trying to generate a dataset that probably breaks the xarray data model. My view is that you should not be trying to generate a netCDF single dataset from this, as the structure is largely against the underlying philosophy. What you want to do is create a *complete* dataset where there are no gaps in the dimensions. This can be done by setting all values to na where there are gaps.

Comment: Thank you all for your great comments. I will change my philosophy about it and try to work with `zarr` files that apparently are more in line with what I should do.